# im getting the `get youtuble app` dialog even if i have the leastest youtube app installed on my physical divice

Tags: android, kotlin, youtube, youtube-data-api

im very new to youtube api when i test the app on my mobile phone a `get youtube app`  dialog is showing even that i have the leastest vertion of the youtube app installed on my divice . i dont know where the error could be or what i did wrong .

```
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeBaseActivity
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeInitializationResult
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
const val KEY_VID_ID  = "dQw4w9WgXcQ"
const val KEY_LIST_ID  = "PLkNqPjK6mmFYDGUceKt73TmoM7srNpDlm"
class youtubePlayer : YouTubeBaseActivity(), YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {
   @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
       val layout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_youtube_player,
           null,
           false) as ConstraintLayout
       setContentView(layout)
       val ytbView = YouTubePlayerView(this)
       ytbView.layoutParams = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(
           ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)
       layout.addView(ytbView)
       ytbView.initialize(getString(R.string.KEY_API_ID ), this)
   }

   override fun onInitializationSuccess(
       provider: YouTubePlayer.Provider?,
       youtubePlayer: YouTubePlayer?,
       wasRestored: Boolean,
   ) {
       if(!wasRestored){
           youtubePlayer?.cueVideo(KEY_VID_ID)
       }
   }

   override fun onInitializationFailure(
       provider: YouTubePlayer.Provider?,
       errorType: YouTubeInitializationResult?,
   ) {
       if(errorType!!.isUserRecoverableError()){
           errorType.getErrorDialog(this , 0).show()
       }else{
           Toast.makeText(this, "an error accured ${errorType}", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
       }
   }
}
'''
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using android 11 and  apov you should add this  code t o thye manefest

````
       <intent>
           <action android:name="com.google.android.youtube.api.service.START" />
       </intent>
   </queries>```
````